# return res.redirect() not working in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, middleware

I am making a database using sequelize as a ORM and  Sqlite3 as a database in NodeJS, but whenever I am redirecting client during signup or successful login its not working the it should and on network tab its showing 304 as status .

```
const express=require('express')
const {db,user}=require('./db.js')

const app=express()
const bodyPraser=require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser=bodyPraser.urlencoded({extended:true})

app.post('/signup',urlencodedParser,async (req,res)=>{
    await user.create({
        username:req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    })
    return res.redirect("/chatApp");
})

app.post('/login',urlencodedParser,async (req,res)=>{
       let emailorUsername=req.body.emailorUsername;
       let password=req.body.password;

       let data=await user.findAll()
       for(let i of data){
           if((i.username==emailorUsername || i.email==emailorUsername )&& i.password==password)
           {   console.log('found')
               return res.redirect("/chatApp")
           }
       }
       return res.redirect("/main")
})


app.use('/main',express.static(__dirname+'/public'))
app.use('/chatApp',express.static(__dirname+'/chatapp'))

db.sync().then(()=>{
      app.listen(4321,()=>{
          console.log('http://localhost:4321')
      })
})
```

see , whenever I am redirecting , to `/chatApp` its not working

And here is from where i am trying to redirect

`
$(()=>{

```
//sending signup request
$("#signup").click(function(){
    $.post('/signup',{
        username:$("#username").val(),
        email:$("#email").val(),
        password:$("#password").val()
    })
})

// sending login request
$("#login").click(()=>{
    console.log("button is pressed");
    $.post('/login',{
        emailorUsername:$("#emailorname").val(),
        password:$("#password1").val()
    })
})
```

})
`

Comment: *"on network tab its showing 304 as status"* - that's what `res.redirect` is supposed to do, could you clarify *"not working"*?

Comment: its means that after inserting the values at `/signup` or checking verified user at `/login` , then after successful signup or user verification its not redirecting the user to path `/chatApp`

Comment: How are you making those requests? If it's being made by JavaScript, it's not e.g. a form element submit, the browser won't change the page automatically. The code you've shown is working fine.

Comment: I am making request using `JQuery` , and can be please elaborate why browser wont refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are posting to the server via AJAX? In that case, it's pointless performing redirects at the server, you need to let the request finish and, if successful, initiate the redirect on the client side.

```
app.post('/signup', urlencodedParser, async (req,res)=>{
  await user.create({
      username:req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password:req.body.password
  });
  res.set('Location', 'url/of/new/user');
  return res.status(201).json({ /* new user object */ 
});

app.post('/login',urlencodedParser,async (req,res)=>{
   let emailorUsername=req.body.emailorUsername;
   let password=req.body.password;

   let data=await user.findAll()
   for(let i of data){
       if((i.username==emailorUsername || i.email==emailorUsername )&& i.password==password)
       {   console.log('found')
           return res.sendStatus(200);
       }
   }
   return res.sendStatus(401);
})

...

//sending signup request
$("#signup").click(function(){
    $.post('/signup',{
        username:$("#username").val(),
        email:$("#email").val(),
        password:$("#password").val()
    }).done(user => {
      console.log('User created', user);
      window.location = '/chatApp';
    }).fail(e => {
      console.log('Create user failed', e);
    })
})

// sending login request
$("#login").click(()=>{
    console.log("button is pressed");
    $.post('/login',{
        emailorUsername:$("#emailorname").val(),
        password:$("#password1").val()
    })
    .done(() => {
      window.location = '/chatApp';
    })
    .fail(e => {
      console.log('Authentication failed');
      window.location = '/main';
    });
})
```

Comment: can you please demonstrate what you are saying

Comment: @PrakashPandey see example

Comment: Yes the code is working fine , but I wanted to send a request after either successful signup or login which can direct user to `/chatApp` , either from server side i.e from `server.js` or from `script.js` . After several research i found out that we can not redirect from a `AJAX` call , and `AJAX ` can be used to only send and get small amount of data without making the page to reload.Moreover I also found out that whenever we want to redirect from a `AJAX` call then the only way to do it is using HTML form .

Comment: Please correct me if i have misunderstood or have till now misconception about the `AJAX` call

Comment: @PrakashPandey you can still send a request to your server and have it redirect the client, it just can't be an AJAX request. So for example, if you want the server to redirect the client after a user is successfully created then you could use a `form` POST instead.